# Nested Folders selection

Tags: tables, lists, checkboxes, selection, multi-selection

I'm working on a selection in which I have a list of folders. This is the structure:

[image]

Let's say I want to select a folder. The folder, its children, and future children will be selected.

[image]

**First Question: What if I'd want to select a folder but not the children folders (i.e. I want to select just the files contained in the turkey folder but not the children folders)? Would I have to select the folder, enter and deselect all the children folders?**

**Second Question: Would you use that state for the root to say that some of its children is selected? To me it's quite common**

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you didn't know, you are designing what is commonly known as a *tree select view*, *checkbox tree* or something along those lines. Might come in handy when searching for reference designs.

> i.e. I want to select just the files contained in the turkey folder

Is `Turkey` a folder? It doesn't show a folder icon, so it looks like a file.

> What if I'd want to select a folder but not the children folders

That should be a matter of expanding `Turkey` and only selecting the files that are a direct child of `Turkey`. Or indeed by selecting `Turkey` and deselecting the unwanted folders.

> Second Question: Would you use that state for the root to say that some of its children is selected? To me it's quite common

The state in your screenshots is the common way to do it. It's called *[indeterminate state](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/i/indeterminate/)*.

Comment: Yes. It's a folder. Anyways, it's true. There should be a close folder next to turkey and east tia.